# android image display as per user choice on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am new to android and would like to know as to why thiswont work.If i have a set of images in my res folder and i want to display them based on users choice such that the Mainactivity is like below:-

```
   public class Activity3 extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.drawable.img1);//here i put the image name
        }
    }

Suppose i use this code snippet
   public class Activity3 extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if(R.id.text1=='1')
      setContentView(R.drawable.img1);
    else
      setContentView(R.drawable.img2);

}
    }
```

This doesnt work.But i would like to know why,how is the android stuff really working.This does seem to me logically right.

Comment: setContentView method is used for setting xml layouts for activities. What you are doing here is trying to set a wrong type of resource as a layout. You should consider learning android from a good book or tutorials if you want to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `drawable` to `setContentView`, but you can do this instead:

```
setContentView(R.layout.MyLayout);     
    ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myviewid);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
```

In each click add `view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);` to change the `imageView` resources.

Answer (score 0):

if you see more carefully the documentation, can see the definition for setContentView method:

```
public void setContentView (int layoutResID)
```

if you note, the method receive a **layoutResId**, the key word is **layout**, remember that android used the logic (view - controller), an activity is the controller and a layout is the view. You can have visual elements in your view, like an image (in android can be contained in an ImageView).

For example, you can define an xml layout to the next way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selected_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</ImageView>
```

this xml only contain an ImageView, in this ImageView with the id selected_image you will show the choice image.

In your activity you need put the next code (imagine the xml layout call image_layout.xml):

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_layout);

        //here you need find the ImageView in this layout
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_image).setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    }
}
```